# How to understand revisions in Debian stable release

Tags: debian, version

At the moment(13.12.2015) Debian 8("jessie") is in revision 2.0, e.g. CD-1 for *amd64* architecture is named *debian-8.2.0-amd64-CD-1.iso*. How to understand revisions for Debian *stable*? For example does *debian-8.2.0-amd64-CD-1.iso* contain updated software versions compared to *debian-8.0.0-amd64-CD-1.iso* only in security-wise? Also in feature-wise? When does stable version of Debian move from one revision to another? As I understand, the feature-, bug-, and security-updates are also released in between the revision and revision is simply a snapshot of the *stable* release at certain point in time?

Comment: please accept the answer if the explanation answers your question or let me know in comments if I can help you more with this topic

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about are called Point releases for debian.
8.0 was the major stable release, however even stable releases require patches.
They usually incorporate the security fixes released until the time of the update and fixes for grave bugs in the current release.

You can get a better understanding about it here: 
https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases/PointReleases

Comment: well usually point releases for debian are released every 2 months is what is written in that link.You dont have to download every point release. Its just for people who are downloading the OS for the first time get the critical updates directly from the release. If you have already installed it, obviously u can update your OS.. :)